# Django admin site downloading style-sheets but not displayed as styled

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin, static-files

I have set up a basic Django system and am testing out the admin app. The admin screen displays with raw styles and not the pretty ones shown in the tutorials and specified in the style-sheets.

Following several other questions, I found this is a common problem caused because Django doesn't normally serve static files. However, it does if DEBUG is switched on and I do have debug switched on. I followed all of the suggestions in the answers anyway to collect static files, etc.

If I enter the static file URLs directly they get downloaded and I can see the files in the developer mode of the browser (both Chrome and Edge). So I think the static files are being served.

Furthermore, if I save the page using the browser, it saves all of the static files and then if I open the main page it is shown with the correct styles. So the styles are working.

So it would seem to me that the files are being served and the browser is getting them and it can render them (from a saved file) but it somehow isn't working when served from Django.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

**EDIT:**

Here is a strange thing: if, using the Chrome developer tool, I select the base.css file, click somewhere in the text of the CSS (say at the end of a line) and then add a space, suddenly the page appears correctly.

If I then do refresh the page it goes back to unstyled again.

**EDIT 2:**

I saw a recommendation to install the *Whitenoise* app to serve static file so I went ahead and did it. I turned off debug and presto! the styles appear. Turning on debug (so I presume django serves the files) and the styles go away. I saved both sites to the file system and compared the directories using a compare tool. There was no difference.

I'm not calling this an answer as the question is:

Why?

Also, I can't have debug on and get styles.

Comment: Just to be sure – you tried to delete your cache and/or open the page in an incognito window? It kinda sounds like a cache issue.

Comment: I tried in incognito mode, tried control-refresh, tried clearing the cache and even tried it in IE (which hasn't seen the site before). Same problem.